# Split the div to two parts and load the content into second half

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div element split and it has few css cards inside it. i want to load that card into a second window ( when i click that card on split div the window should divide itself into two and load that card into the second div.
But far i am not able to slit the div on click only.

```js
 var  $m = $("#split"), size = 2;

$m.click(function(){
  
    var  _size = $m.width/size;
    var i= "sec";
    
    
        $m.append(
            $('<div id='+ i +'/>')
            .css('background-color', 'white'));
       

    $m.find('> div').css({ width:_size, height:_size });

});
```

```css
#split{
height:700px;
width:500px;
}

.tu{
        height: 162px;
    width: 350;
    float: left;
   
    position: relative;
    
}

 .gradient {
  
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="split" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="tu">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="gradient">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/18292/production/_93626989_1902979_10152134574292143_2095474865755623618_n.jpg">
              <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
              I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
```

What i want is when i click .tu class the #split  should divide into two and show load tu into second half

Comment: Did either of these answers help you solve the problem? If not how can we improve our answers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/5kj0xoh4/

```js
var  $m = $("#split"), size = 2;

$m.click(function(){
  
  var  _size = $m.width/size;
  var i= "sec";
 $m.append(
    $('<div id='+ i +'></div>')
     .html($m.html())
      .css('background-color', 'white'));
   
    $m.find('> div').css({ width:_size, height:_size }
  );

});
```

```css
#split{
height:700px;
width:500px;
}

.tu{
  height: 162px;
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
}

.gradient {
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%); 
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="split" style="width:100%;">
  <div class="tu">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="gradient">
      <div class="card-image">
        <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/18292/production/_93626989_1902979_10152134574292143_2095474865755623618_n.jpg">
        <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
        I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Change the width of `.tu` container from `350` to `50%`.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: thanks for the solution. but now i am stuck at another problem that their are around 10 divs with class .tu and all 10 are replicated to the second half. But i only want to load a particular div. I know that i need to give separate id to all but will that help because i tried its not helping.

Comment: Well this doesn't actually split the div like you wanted it just duplicates all .tu classes. My answer actually splits the div and then adds 1 new tu class.

Comment: @RaghavPatnecha . Have a look into the solution https://jsfiddle.net/5kj0xoh4/1/ . Hope this will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up fixing a few things I would just look at the changes i made between edits.

I think this is what your looking for:

```js
var $m = $("#split");

$m.on("click", function(){
    var tu = $m.find(".tu").first();
    var i = tu.length + 1;
    var _size = tu.width()/i;

    $m.append(
        $('<div id='+ i +' class="tu"></div>')
            .html($m.find(".tu").first().html())
            .css('background-color', 'white'));
       

    $m.find('.tu').css({ width:_size, height:_size });

});
```

```css
#split{
height:700px;
width:500px;
}

.tu{
    height: 162px;
    width: 350px;
    float: left;
   
    position: relative;
    
}

 .gradient {
  
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;

    background-image: linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%); 
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(-180deg,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,.35) 100%);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.1/css/materialize.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row" id="split" style="width:100%;">
        <div class="tu">
          <div class="card">
              <div class="gradient">
            <div class="card-image">
              <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/18292/production/_93626989_1902979_10152134574292143_2095474865755623618_n.jpg">
              <span class="card-title">Card Title</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-content">
              <p>I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information.
              I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.</p>
            </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        </div>
```

Comment: i want it to divide horizontally not vertically